# Scanner only reads for loop once? - Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a class where you input any number of grades (A-F) and calculates the GPA and returns the GPA and eligibility to extracurricular activities. It seems like the scanner only allows one input, then prints the GPA and eligibility. 
So far this is what I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Grades
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double myGPA;
        int myNumClasses;
        double myValue;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Press any other lettter to calculate.");
        System.out.print("Enter grades: ");
        String input = sc.nextLine();

        myValue = 0;
        myNumClasses = 0;
        myGPA = 0;

        for (String next = sc.next(); input.equalsIgnoreCase("a") ||     input.equalsIgnoreCase("b") || 
        input.equalsIgnoreCase("c")|| input.equalsIgnoreCase("d") || input.equalsIgnoreCase("f"); next = sc.next())
        {
            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("a"))
            {
                myValue += 4.0;
                myNumClasses += 1;
            }

            else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("b"))
            {
                myValue += 3.0;
                myNumClasses += 1;
            }

            else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("c"))
            {
                myValue += 2.0;
                myNumClasses += 1;
            }

            else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("d"))
            {
                myValue += 1.0;
                myNumClasses += 1;
            }

            else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("f"))
            {   
               myNumClasses += 1;
            }

            myGPA = myValue / myNumClasses;

            if (myGPA >= 2.0 && myNumClasses >= 4)
            {
                System.out.println("Eligible");
            }
            else if (myNumClasses < 4)
            {
                System.out.println("Ineligible, taking less than 4 classes");
            }
            else if (myGPA >= 2.0 && input.equalsIgnoreCase("f"))
            {
                System.out.println("Ineligible, gpa above 2.0 but has F grade");
            }
            else if (myGPA <= 2.0 && input.equalsIgnoreCase("f"))
            {
                System.out.println("Ineligible, gpa below 2.0 and has F grade");
            }
            else if (myGPA < 2.0)
            {
                System.out.println("Inelligible, gpa below 2.0");
            }
            System.out.println("Your GPA = " + myGPA);
         }
      }
}
```

Comment: You never update `input` - not sure if you want too though, this is pretty unclear code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // It looks like your missing a for loop. I just copied some of your 
    //code and ran it through a for loop. The rest of the code is kind of unclear. 

    System.out.println("Enter the number of grades you will enter: ");
    int userAns = sc.nextInt();

    for (int index = 0; index <= userAns; index++)
    {
       System.out.println("Press any other letter to calculate.");
       System.out.print("Enter grades: ");
       String input = sc.nextLine();
    }
```

Comment: You might want to try storing the values in an array and then recalling the array data with a for loop to assign the letter grade a numeric number. After that you can create a method to average the numeric number to create a GPA. Then use a boolean to set to true if eligible or false if ineligible.